# Why 256 outputs are needed in SemiHard Online Learning predicting MNIST?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, triplet

[TensorFlow Addons Losses](https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/tutorials/losses_triplet)

I study Triplet Loss using the above article. The labels's numbers are from 0 to 9 trying below code.

```
for images_batch, labels_batch in train_dataset:
print('images batch shape:', images_batch.shape)
print('labels batch', labels_batch.shape)
print(labels_batch)
break
```

Then I confirm how is the model like below?

```
Model: "sequential_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 28, 28, 64)        320       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2 (None, 14, 14, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)          (None, 14, 14, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)            (None, 14, 14, 32)        8224      
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_3 (MaxPooling2 (None, 7, 7, 32)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_3 (Dropout)          (None, 7, 7, 32)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 1568)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 256)               401664    
_________________________________________________________________
lambda_1 (Lambda)            (None, 256)               0         
=================================================================
Total params: 410,208
Trainable params: 410,208
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

However, I have a question.
What does last layer's output numbers, 256 means?
I think in general, when we use MNIST, output's layer's numbers are 10 and changing the output's number to categorical, one-hot.
In this case, I really don't know why the output layer's numbers are 256 and labels still like 0 to 9.
Please enlighten me on the specifics.

Answer (score 0):

> As first introduced in the FaceNet paper, TripletLoss is a loss
> function that trains a neural network to closely embed features of the
> same class while maximizing the distance between embeddings of
> different classes. To do this an anchor is chosen along with one
> negative and one positive sample.

This is the first line in the tutorial. The output of the model is not classification but instead embeddings which can be visualized.
As mentioned in the above quote the aim of this neural network is to learn parameters such that the distance between embeddings of the different classes will be maximum.

If you scroll down the tutorial you can see the visualized embeddings. You can consider embeddings as points on multidimensional space. Each example will have its own label and in turn, will have its own embeddings.

You can use these embedding instead of images to train your classifier.

Comment: That means embedded features  are only extracted in this code. If I try to classifier MNIST, Do I have to use k-NN and so on.

Comment: These embeddings can act as input to any machine learning algorithm. You can use it with k-NN, SVM, Logistic Regression, Neural Networks, or any other algorithm of your choice.